# How to convert functions to class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, flutter-dependencies

Hi team i have taken code from site which is used to get the user geolocation with the help of geolocation but i need to change the functions in the code to class so i can easily access anywhere.Need advice

here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocationPage> createState() => _LocationPageState();
}

class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  String? _currentAddress;
  Position? _currentPosition;

  Future<bool> _handleLocationPermission() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Location services are disabled. Please enable the services')));
      return false;
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(content: Text('Location permissions are denied')));
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.')));
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentPosition() async {
    final hasPermission = await _handleLocationPermission();

    if (!hasPermission) return;
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() => _currentPosition = position);
      _getAddressFromLatLng(_currentPosition!);
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getAddressFromLatLng(Position position) async {
    await placemarkFromCoordinates(
            _currentPosition!.latitude, _currentPosition!.longitude)
        .then((List<Placemark> placemarks) {
      Placemark place = placemarks[0];
      setState(() {
        _currentAddress =
            '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.subAdministrativeArea}, ${place.postalCode}';
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Location Page")),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('LAT: ${_currentPosition?.latitude ?? ""}'),
              Text('LNG: ${_currentPosition?.longitude ?? ""}'),
              Text('ADDRESS: ${_currentAddress ?? ""}'),
              const SizedBox(height: 32),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: _getCurrentPosition,
                child: const Text("Get Current Location"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i would like to convert the functions available in the above code to class so i can able to access anywhere

Comment: use static keyword

Comment: Which Function you want to use anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';


class GeolocationClass{
  Future<bool> handleLocationPermission(BuildContext context) async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      if(context.mounted){
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
            content: Text(
                'Location services are disabled. Please enable the services')));
      }
      return false;
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        if(context.mounted){
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
              const SnackBar(content: Text('Location permissions are denied')));
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      if(context.mounted){
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
            content: Text('Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.')));
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  Future<void> getCurrentPosition(BuildContext context, Position currentPosition,String currentAddress) async {
    final hasPermission = await handleLocationPermission(context);

    if (!hasPermission) return;
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
        .then((Position position) {
      currentPosition = position;
      getAddressFromLatLng(currentPosition,currentAddress);
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }

  Future<void> getAddressFromLatLng(Position currentPosition,String currentAddress) async {
    await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude)
        .then((List<Placemark> placeMarks) {
           Placemark place = placeMarks[0];
           currentAddress = '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.subAdministrativeArea}, ${place.postalCode}';
    }).catchError((e) {
      debugPrint(e);
    });
  }
}
```

To access these, just create an object of GeolocationClass where you want to call these methods:

```
final geolocationObject = GeolocationClass();
```

and call them like this:

```
geolocationObject.handleLocationPermission(context);
geolocationObject.getCurrentPosition(context,_currentPosition,_currentAddress);
```

make sure to pass context and other parameters.